# Why when I'm using `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on same element, `*ngFor` add null item to array which I'm iterating?

Tags: templates, angular

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbKB3.png)
,
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99QbC.png).
But if i change *ngIf directive to [hidden] property, it looks nice, and there is no null item.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add code directly to the question instead of linking to external resources.

Comment: seems like you don't even need that `ngIf` , `ngFor` doesn't render if `length` is `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this if you are using below beta 8, because angular2 does't support *ngIf anf *ngFor on same element beta 8([see here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6304) ) and below -

```
<template [ngIf]='hotel.rooms.length > 0'>
 <div *ngFor='#room of hotel.rooms; #i=index'>
 ... Your code
 </div>
</template>
```

Hope it helps you, if not provide your code as plnkr ill help you.